# Getting value of disable radio button control in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

Not getting value of radio button which i disable using JQuery before page submit.

Comment: Show us some code.... :)

Comment: I guess the browser doesn't send disbled fields to the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ASP.NET 2.0 doesn’t submit client-side
>   disabled controls by default

You can use [**HtmlForm.SubmitDisabledControls Property**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlform.submitdisabledcontrols.aspx) to specify whether to force controls disabled on the client to submit their values when the page posts back.